# (Windows) When to delete object and device context?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, native

Suppose I create a function that process a bitmap in memory dc and return it

```
HBITMAP paint (HWND hwnd)
{

HDC windc = ::GetWindowDC(hwnd);
HDC memdc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(windc);
HBITMAP bitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(windc,100,100); //Don't bother with the height and width
::SelectObject(memdc,(HGDIOBJ)bitmap);

/* DeleteDC(windc) here? */

//do the painting
//...
//painting done

/*DeleteDC(memdc) here? */

return bitmap;

/* Code does not reach here */
/* So where do I put DeleteObject(bitmap)? */
}
```

My question is where and when to delete the bitmap? Also, does deleting windc affect the memdc? or memdc is purely created (and does not contain information that "points" to the windc) ? If that is true, then deleting windc after bitmap and memdc are created (before any painting) is appropriate.

Comment: Important - Call ReleaseDC for a corresponding call to GetWindowDC. (In your code above, you are calling DeleteDC).  Call DeleteDC only for DCs you create yourself (e.g. CreateCompatibleDC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DeleteDC(windc);
```

**Never.** You have to call [ReleaseDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(windc); instead.

After `::CreateCompatibleDC(windc);` you don't need `windc` and don't care what happens with it. HDC returned by CreateCompatibleDC just derives some of the parameters (device dependent pixel representation, etc) but does not refer to `windc` in any way.

Instead of this:

```
::SelectObject(memdc,(HGDIOBJ)bitmap);

//do the painting
//...
//painting done

/*DeleteDC(memdc) here? */

return bitmap;
```

You have to do something like this:

```
HGDIOBJ prevBitmap = ::SelectObject(memdc,(HGDIOBJ)bitmap);

//do the painting
//...
//painting done

::SelectObject(memdc,prevBitmap);
DeleteDC(memdc);

return bitmap;
```

Comment: So I do not need to delete my own created bitmap?

Comment: @biloon: "So I do not need to delete my own created bitmap?" Of course you have to delete your bitmap when you no longer need it. But why would you want to delete it here if you return it from the function? When you're done with the bitmap then delete it and don't return its handle anywhere after that (this handle is no longer valid).