# Is it necessary to delete a rendering context and destroy a device context?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

Is it necessary to delete the HDC and HRC when using the win32 api for OpenGL? I would think the Win32API would destroy them upon the window's closing?

Clarification: The HRC is a HGLRC object.

Comment: Possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421287/windows-when-to-delete-object-and-device-context

Comment: Did you create the DC?  Or did you just to a GetDC on a window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it "necessary"? If your process terminates itself after closing the window, no. Windows will clean up outstanding handles of these type.

*Should* you do it? Absolutely. You should always clean up objects you use in your application. Dropping things on the floor for the OS to clean up is not good practice. If for no other reason than the fact that you might want to create a new window after closing the old one. In which case, you have this garbage HGLRC lying around taking up precious resources.

Answer (score 0):

You have to worry about other things than just the window being closed.  For example, read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/06/10399678.aspx, which says that the owner of an object cannot delete it while it's selected into a DC.

Answer (score 0):

Release (don't delete) the HDC as soon as you can.  I have done OpenGL, so I don't entirely know what the HGLRC is used for, but I suspect that's handled similarly.  Getting handles is cheap; holding on to them can be problematic.